# TableLayout hides the margins of an ImageView

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a table layout with 2 table rows like this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splashBunny"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screenbunny"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/taketest"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/taketest" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

On the splashBunny `ImageView` I start a spring animation with a fade in animation. The spring animation starts from an initial value(small image view) and then ends up on it's final value(bigger imageview) with the maximum spring effect.

The problem is that the `TableRow` obscures the spring effect on the final value... more exactly it looks like this:

[image: Screenshoot]

As you can see the edges of the ImageView are cut by the `TableRow` on the spring animation maximum effect, after this the image "resizes" back to the normal value.

My question is this. How can I avoid this problem to not cut the edges of the ImageView inside the `TableRow` on spring animation, to look similar to this:

[image: Screenshoot2]

Comment: Why two table rows? Why not to use single image view?

Comment: Because on some point I will add more image view's to the table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered how to not cut the edges of the image view with android:padding on the tablerow!